# Controle de acesso e permissão

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, segurança, tomcat

Estou com um projeto de CRUD pra gerenciar docentes e cursos de uma faculdade usando jsf+primefaces+jpa. Meu problema é o seguinte:

- Existem os usuarios que são os cordenadores dos cursos e os usuarios que são funcionarios. Os funcionarios tem acesso a lista de todos os cursos cadastrados na base, porém os cordenadores só podem visualizar os dados do curso dele.

  - Exemplo: 
    Usuario normal abre a tela do crud e ve um datatable mostrando todos os cursos. Já um cordenador ve um datatable mostrando apenas o curso atribuido a ele.

Como eu faço pra restringir esse tipo de acesso a um usuário?

Comment: Basicamente você pode colocar uma verificação manual em cada ligar que verifica o tipo de usuário e dá ou não acesso. Nos menus você pode ocultar os itens que ele não deveria acessar. Nas telas você verifica se tem o acesso é lança um erro se não tiver, para o caso de um espertinho acessar a URL diretamente. Como isso é feito depende de como seu sistema está implementado. Para algo mais avançado você pode tentar o Spring Security, mas diria que não vale o esforço se for um sistema acadêmico. Há outras perguntas e respostas sobre Spring Security por aqui é só pesquisar.

Answer (score -1):

Cara, voce teria que fazer um userStatic, pegar o id que esta logado e comparar a permissão, você usa filter ou springSecurity ?
vc pode criar as permissões com um booleano tambem.
        EX.:

```
@Override
      public List<Ordens> listarTodos() {
    S  tring sql = "select o from Ordens as o inner join o.usuario as u where u.id"
            + " = "+UserStatic.getUsuario().getId();

    if(UserStatic.getUsuario().getPermissaoUsuario().equals(PermissaoUsuario.USER))
         return getEntityManager().createQuery(sql).getResultList();

      if(UserStatic.getUsuario().getPermissaoUsuario().equals(PermissaoUsuario.ENCARREGADO))
         return getEntityManager().createQuery(sql).getResultList();


    return super.listarTodos();
```

Answer (score -1):

Melhor que filtro puro não existe. O SpringSecurity também filtro, mas específico e engessado.

Exemplo:

```
/**
 * Filter para tratar login no sistema
 */
@WebFilter(
        filterName = "all", urlPatterns = { "/*" }, dispatcherTypes = { DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.FORWARD,
                DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR })
public class NossoFilterAllRequest implements Filter
{

    /**
     * urlPatterns = { "/*" } isso vai fazer com todas as resições passem por aqui
     */

    /**
     * @Objetivo Implementar o filtro de logar no sistema
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest requestServlet, ServletResponse responseServlet, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        try
        {
            final HttpServletRequest rq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            final HttpServletResponse rp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            final SeuObjetoSessaoLogin objSession = (SeuObjetoSessaoLogin) rq.getSession().getAttribute("login");
            //sua lógica
             chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {
        //se precisar logicas de baixar algum serviço, executa quando para o serviço
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        //se precisar iniciar alguma lógica.. executa quando inicia o serviço
    }
}
```